# How do I make a retry on PHP Curl after three errors

Tags: php, curl

How do I make a retry of three attempts on a failed PHP Curl call? I notice that my code seems to stop working. I tried using a curl_error, but no success. The code is listed below:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://somewhere.com/api/';

//set up parameters to pass via POST
$data = array('param1' => 'Parameter 1');
$data_json = json_encode($data);

$return = '';
$ctr = 0;
$ch = curl_init($url);
//I want to have a retry of three times
while($ctr++ < 3){
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if(curl_error($ch)){
    //try again
  }
  else{
    $obj=json_decode($result);
    $return = $obj->{'return'};
  }
}
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

I was hoping that the timeout of 10 (seconds?) would force the Curl call to terminate.

The JSFiddle link is at https://jsfiddle.net/jun3178_dolor/feqyz2vp/

Comment: you tried to run php code in jsfiddle? Why?

Comment: I've revised my test code to call an IP API. I've intentionally entered a wrong URL to force an error. So far, this seems to have worked. I've updated JSFiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP's cURL extension does not include the retry flags (See --retry at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).  You have to manually code in a custom ability to look for the response code (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) or last error number via https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php.

I've answered this question due to the page being a top result for "php curl retry".